# How to discuss preferences / ask which do you prefer in Mandarin

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin

How does one discuss preferences/ask what someone prefers out of a series of options?

Do you just list each option followed by 好不好？

Thanks

Comment: You can 1. Write down all the different ways you can think of in English. 2. Use Google Translate to translate them into Chinese, 3. Study the results to understand the structures, 4. Ask what you can't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, there are two methods.

1. List the options first and then ask "which do you prefer?" You have to use a proper verb according to the options.

中餐、西餐、日本料理，你喜歡吃哪一種？

登山、游泳、慢跑、快走，你愛做哪一種運動？

2. Reverse the order.

你喜歡吃蘋果、香蕉、橘子、西瓜，還是木瓜？

放假的時候，你喜歡看書、玩遊戲、聽音樂，還是睡覺？

Answer (score 2):

patterns:

你喜欢thing1, thing2... 还是thing n？

你觉得thing1 好 还是 thing2 好 还是 thing3 好

Answer (score 0):

You also have the possibility to use the word 最 'the most'.

Following young99 methods:

in 1.

中餐、西餐、日本料理，你**最**喜歡吃(**是**)哪一種？

in 2.

你(**是**)**最**喜歡吃蘋果、香蕉、橘子、西瓜，還是木瓜？

With 是 for emphasis.